# How to delete / mark as played multiple podcast episodes played in iOS11

Tags: iphone, podcasts, ios

My podcast app decided to mark as unplayed 200+ episodes of a podcast I have listened to for years. In iOS11 I'm not even sure how to mark these as unplayed individually anymore, let alone altogether. Is there a way to do this? I am currently trying to go through and delete each, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: This may depend on what Podcast app you are using. Can you edit the question to include this?